# How to filter column in Data frame based on text containing symbol #

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, for-loop, filter

Hi have a Data frame with two columns which looks like this:

```
Index  Text

0      READ MY NEW OP-ED: IRREVERSIBLE – Many Effects...
1      #COVID19 is linked to more #diabetes diagnoses...
2      #COVID19: IRREVERSIBLE – Many Effects...
3      READ MY NEW OP-ED: IRREVERSIBLE – Many Effects...
4      Advanced healthcare at your fingertips\nhttps:...
```

I am trying keep only the rows which contain the #symbol, so based on my data frame above my desired output is:

```
Index  Text

1      #COVID19 is linked to more #diabetes diagnoses...
2      #COVID19: IRREVERSIBLE – Many Effects...
```

I have tried several ways to obtain that unsuccessfully, my latest code attempt was:

```
for column in twt_text:
    print(twt_text['text'].str.contains('#'))
```

But the output generated was not at all what I expected:

```
0   False
1   True
2   True
3   False
4   False
```

Any idea or insight on how I can obtain the output I want based on text containing # ?

Answer (score 0):

You could build a selection mask and use that to filter the rows:

```
df[df['Text'].str.contains('#')]
```

**Result**

```
                                                Text
1  #COVID19 is linked to more #diabetes diagnoses...
2           #COVID19: IRREVERSIBLE – Many Effects...
```